# changing display function in define-word package

Tags: message, popup

How to replace the displayfn from `message` to a function which displays the result in a temporary window? (I have limited knowledge of elisp.)

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! It's not really clear what you want to do. Could you try to be more explicit? What is the 'define-word' package?

Answer (score 1):

To give a bit of context, `define-word` is an Emacs mode which provides dictionary definitions given a word [1]. By default it sends its output to the `messages` buffer, but it provides an overridable display function. Here's my solution to redirect the output, which is by no means an "advanced" one. First, based on the answer by [choroba](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2526/choroba), I defined my display function like so:

```lisp
(defun my/display-word (&rest args)
  "Create a buffer for display word instead of using messages."
  (interactive)
  (let
      ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "Define Word")))
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (set-buffer-major-mode buffer)
    (apply 'insert args)
    (display-buffer buffer))
  )
```

Then I copied the code from Henrik Lissner's config [2], which loops through all available services and adds them to the alist:

```lisp
(setq define-word-displayfn-alist
      (cl-loop for (service . _) in define-word-services
               collect (cons service #'my/display-word)))
```

The end result is as follows:

[image: screenshot]

If you are interested in the details of my investigation, please see the ticket I raised against the project [3].

**Update 1**

Actually, I found the creation of many buffers quite annoying so I updated the function to this:

```lisp
(defun my/display-word (&rest args)
  "Create a buffer for display word instead of using messages."
  (interactive)
  (let
      ((buffer (get-buffer-create "Define Word")))
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (erase-buffer)
    (set-buffer-major-mode buffer)
    (apply 'insert args)
    (display-buffer buffer))
  )
```

[1] [define-word GitHub repo](https://github.com/abo-abo/define-word)

[2] [Henrik Lissner's config](https://git.v0.io/hlissner/doom-emacs/src/commit/7742813a060843dea12bb4aa9c3eb83525b13a7e/modules/tools/lookup/config.el#L189)

[3] [#29: Redefining display function to output to a buffer instead of messages](https://github.com/abo-abo/define-word/issues/29)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
(message "ahoy")
```

create a new buffer, switch to it and insert the message there:

```
(progn (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer "message"))
       (insert "ahoy"))
```